# SQL: Filtering joined tables

Tags: sql, inner-join

here I simplify my use case: I have N.2 Tables: **DUT** (Device under test) containing the device information and **TestResults** containing the DUT test measurements. The primary key UUTid joins the two tables:

Table **DUT**:

- UUTid (Primary Key)
- SerialNumber
- Date
- Operator
  …

Table **TestResults**:

- UUTid (Foreign Key)
- TestName
- TestType
- TestResult
  …

Well by means of an INNER JOIN I get test details from the TestResults Table by filtering on DUT Serial Number, but is there any way to consider ONLY DUTs whose TestResult and TestName values (from table TestResults) contain a specific value?
IN other words I'd like to select all Tests for that refers to a specific DUT SerialNumber (a specific primary key in **DUT** table) only when at least one test is namedd "ABC" and its result is "123".

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do that, however you should [edit] your question to provide [proper sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info), rdbms (product and version, please!) your current attempt and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

first you have to join the two tables base on UUTid, afterwards you place your conditions in the WHERE clause.

to use more than one condition you can use AND,OR.

AND for both conditions to come TRUE , while OR is for one condition to come TRUE

```
select * from DUT a 
inner join TestResults
On a.UUTid = b.UUTid
where a.SerialNumber = 'XXXX' and b.TestName = 'ABC' and b.TestResult = '123'
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers, explain how it is an answer to the question & what the problems or misconceptions in the question were. [answer]

Comment: Also, this will not produce the OP's expected results. Hint: Exists might come in handy here....

Comment: @ZoharPeled  can you please explain what you mean by OP`s?

Comment: Sure.OP stands for Original Poster (the person that posted the question) or sometimes Original Post (the question itself). That's standard StackExchange jargon.